# Subsequence for $\{\sin n\}$ that converges to $c \in(-1/2,1/2)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a subsequence for $\{\sin n\}$ that converges to $c \in(-1/2,1/2)$.

Since $\sin n$ is bounded , we must have a convergent Subsequence. But Can we make the limit between - $1 / 2$ and $1 / 2$?

Comment: Use the fact that $\Bbb Z+\pi\Bbb Z$ is a dense subgroup of $\Bbb R$ to show that each point of $[-1,1]$ is sequential limit of $\big\{\sin(n)\big\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma: If $A$ is an arc on the unit circle of arc length at least $1,$ then $ e^{in} \in A$ for infinitely many $n.$

Proof: The sequence $e^{i n}$ marches around the circle infinitely many times in steps of arc length $1.$ In every orbit of the circle, the sequence lands in $A$ at least once. This gives the lemma.

Now consider the arc $\{e^{it}: t\in (-\pi/6,\pi/6)\}.$ The length of this arc is greater than $1,$ so there exists a small $\delta >0$ such that

$$A=\{e^{it}: t\in [-\pi/6+\delta,\pi/6-\delta]\}$$

has length $1.$ The lemma implies $e^{in}\in A$ for infinitely many $n.$ For every such $n,$ $|\sin n| \le \sin (\pi/6-\delta)< 1/2.$ A subsequence of these $n$'s will then lead to the result.